# Longest-time-verifying block

Tags: blockchain, block

I heard that there was an old block with one transaction and it takes 20 seconds of CPU time to verify.

1) Which block was it? I forgot its block height.

2) Is there a block that takes more time to verify? Or is there a similar block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bb41a757f405890fb0f5856228e23b715702d714d59bf2b1feb70d8b2b4e3e08](https://blockchain.info/tx/bb41a757f405890fb0f5856228e23b715702d714d59bf2b1feb70d8b2b4e3e08) is usually the transaction referred to as being the megatransaction that took seconds to verify. It is the only non-coinbase transaction in block [000000000000000003dd2fdbb484d6d9c349d644d8bbb3cbfa5e67f639a465fe](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000003dd2fdbb484d6d9c349d644d8bbb3cbfa5e67f639a465fe).

Nowadays this transaction is verified much faster than 20 seconds. Last time I benchmarked this, it was ~1 second. With the introduction of `assumevalid` in Bitcoin Core 0.14, the transaction's signatures are no longer fully validated so it takes the same time as most other blocks, ~60 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you are looking for, but it may be.

Here you have a type of transaction that takes 3 minutes to verify, and that was reported back in 2013. ([CVE-2013-2292](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures#CVE-2013-2292)). Moreover, in [Sergio Demian Lener's blog](https://bitslog.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/a-bitcoin-transaction-that-takes-5-hours-to-verify/) you can find a related topic, where he explains how he found a vulnerability that used the `FindAndDelete` function and `OP_CODESEPARATOR` to create a transaction that toke up more than 5 hours to verify.